# How to test postgres database connection on host?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

I used **pg_isready -h localhost** which gives output as **localhost:5432 - accepting connections**

But when i used my host-ip instead of localhost ,it gives output as 
**pg_isready -h 18.191.7.185**
output is **18.191.7.185:5432 - no response**

My localhost isn't my ip-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. Verify with

```
ping localhost
```

which will show you the IP address that `localhost` resolves to.

The “loopback interface” is a special network interface that only contains your computer.

The cause of the problem is probably that the PostgreSQL parameter `listen_addresses`, which specifies the network interfaces on which PostgreSQL is listening, is set to the default value `localhost`.

Change the value to `*` and restart PostgreSQL, and it should work.

A second possibility is that you have restrictive firewall settings on your machine. Actually, reading your question again, that is probably your problem, since you are receiving no response rather that an error saying that nothing is listening on that port.

Comment: ping localhost gives ip as '127.0.0.1' and pg_isready -h 127.0.0.1 is accepting connections. but my host-ip is different not 127.0.0.1. I also changes listen_addresses to '*' ..still not working

Comment: Exactly, that confirms my answer (the last paragraph). Disable the firewall and try again.

Comment: I did by **sudo ufw disable** but didn't work..FYI i am on kuberenetes master node and **hostname -I** doesn't list my ip-address as well.

Comment: You should ask your system administrator for help.

Comment: well i am student ..not working somewhere.. so no system administrator..anyway thanks for you help

Comment: Maybr you should add your kubernetes setup to the question and tag it appropriately. At any rate, the problem is network related, which should help with debugging.